# Why does my cable modem need a MAC address?

Tags: isp, cable-modem

Per title. Isn't a cable modem just working on the physical layer? Vs Ethernet. It's not my default gateway. Does the next hop at the ISP see my PCs Mac or the cable modems Mac? Both?

Comment: a cable modem is a TCP/IP device, therefore it has a MAC address.  It probably has 2 or more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does modem MAC address mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/231488/what-does-modem-mac-address-mean)

Comment: No. I'm asking under what circumstances does my cable modems Mac address come into play. It's not routing anything.

Comment: Actually it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cable modems may incorporate a router and a DHCP server to provide the LAN with IP network addressing. From a data forwarding and network topology perspective, this router functionality is typically kept distinct from the cable modem functionality (at least logically) even though the two may share a single enclosure and appear as one unit, sometimes called a residential gateway. So, the cable modem function will have its own IP address and MAC address as will the router.

Per https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_modem

So my cable modem acts as a layer one or two forwarder device.

But, for the ISP to able to access it from their end it would require a mac and IP.

Comment: Your modem being discoverable by your ISP has little to do with the fact it has a MAC address, in that, it has a IP address because of the MAC address and that's the reason your ISP can access it

Answer (score 1):

> Per title. Isn't a cable modem just working on the physical layer? Vs Ethernet. It's not my default gateway.

No. A modern cable modem has a network layer and is externally visible on the cable network. This is, at a minimum, needed for administration and monitoring.

> Does the next hop at the ISP see my PCs Mac or the cable modems Mac? Both?

On most modern networks, the next hop at the ISP is the cable modem. It has to be since your PC doesn't speak the network protocol that's used on the cable network.